# Google Analytics API v3 OAuth2Authenticator Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am getting a weird issue when trying to auth against googles analytics API.

Can someone help?

Here's the code:

```
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Analytics.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Public Class GoogleAnalytics

Private _scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue()
Private _clientID As String = "nnnnnnnnnnnnnn@developer.gserviceaccount.com" '"1038052825878.apps.googleusercontent.com"
Private _keyFile As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\key\nnnnnnnnnnnnnn-privatekey.p12"
Private _keyPassword As String = "notasecret"

Private Function Auth() As OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient)
    Dim _desc As New AuthorizationServerDescription
    _desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description
    Dim _key As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(_keyFile, _keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
    Dim _client As AssertionFlowClient = New AssertionFlowClient(_desc, _key) With {.ServiceAccountId = _clientID, .Scope = _scope}
    Return New OAuth2Authenticator(Of AssertionFlowClient)(_client, AddressOf AssertionFlowClient.GetState)

End Function

Public Sub Analytics()
    Dim _gas As AnalyticsService = New AnalyticsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.Authenticator = Auth()})
    Dim _r As DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest = _gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:nnnnnnnn",
                                                                    "2013-01-01",
                                                                    "2013-01-31",
                                                                    "ga:visitors")
    _r.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath"
    _r.Sort = "-ga:visitors"
    _r.MaxResults = 5

    Dim _d As GaData = _r.Execute() '<------ ERROR HAPPENS HERE

    For Each h In _d.ColumnHeaders
        Console.WriteLine(h.Name)
    Next

    For Each row In _d.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(row(0) & " ------ " + row(1))
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Class
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
User does not have any Google Analytics account. [403]
Errors [
Message[User does not have any Google Analytics account.] Location[ - ]     Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]
```

The ga: ID is correct, and the `_clientID` is correct in-so-far-as my APIs Console is showing me.

The only other thing I can think of is to re-try generating the .p12 file... other than that, I am at a loss

Comment: Even regenerating a new .p12 file is producing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why I am answering this myself is so this does not get deleted.

What I ended up having to do was add the service developer email address to my analytics account, and it works!